# mean of difference between numbers in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this data frame:

```
df = {user:  ['a', 'a','b','b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'b'],
  otherData:['bnd', 'smd','rtf','ldf', 'gfd', 'egq', 'wqd, 'lvm', 'zrb'],
  grades: [12, 9, 7, 11, 7, 9, 5, 8, 1] 
}
```

for each user, I want to calculate the mean for " minimum grade + differences between next grades".
for example grades of user a,  are 5, 9, 12. I want (5+4+3)/3 = 4

in the end, for this example I want this result:

| user | res |
| --- | --- |
| a | 4 |
| b | 3.666 |
| c | 4 |
| d | 9 |

I prefer to solve it using pandas or numpy methods and functions.

Comment: The answers below are a bit overpowered, as if user `a` has sorted grades `x,y,z` ; then you want to output `(x + (y-x) + (z-y))/3`. But that is exactly equal to `z / 3`, as `x` and `y` will simplify with themselves !

Thus you simply want the maximum of the grades for each user, divided by the number of grades he has.

Comment: @RandomGuy that's a superb observation thank you, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @RandomGuy - Wau, so it means need divide max value by counts. If never mind added to answer.

Comment: @RandomGuy yes! you're right! thanks.
can you post your useful comment as an answer to my question?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Because I'm not really good with pandas, and I struggled to convert this dictionnary into a dataframe ^^

Comment: @Kia you can accept jezrael answer, he added my observation ;)

Comment: @MustafaAydın Thanks, but it was more the part to group grades by users where I had troubles. I have few time available today, thus I decided to simply post a comment rather than look how to write it properly ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For improve performance first sorting values per groups (by both columns), then get differencies, replace first misisng value by first value (minimal) and get `mean`:

```
f = lambda x: x.diff().fillna(x).mean()
#numpy alternative
#f = lambda x: np.mean(np.append(np.diff(x),x.iat[0]))
df2 = df.sort_values(['user','grades']).groupby('user')['grades'].agg(f).reset_index(name='res')
print (df2)
  user       res
0    a  4.000000
1    b  3.666667
2    c  4.000000
3    d  9.000000
```

Alternative:

```
df = df.sort_values(['user','grades'])

df['res'] = df.groupby('user')['grades'].diff().fillna(df['grades'])
print (df)
  user otherData  grades  res
6    a       wqd       5  5.0
1    a       smd       9  4.0
0    a       bnd      12  3.0
8    b       zrb       1  1.0
2    b       rtf       7  6.0
3    b       ldf      11  4.0
4    c       gfd       7  7.0
7    c       lvm       8  1.0
5    d       egq       9  9.0

df2 = df.groupby('user', as_index=False)['res'].mean()
print (df2)
  user       res
0    a  4.000000
1    b  3.666667
2    c  4.000000
3    d  9.000000
```

Solution by comment by [RandomGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983224/mean-of-difference-between-numbers-in-pandas/67983303#comment120160144_67983224)  is fastest:

> if user a has sorted grades x,y,z ; then you want to output (x + (y-x) + (z-y))/3. But that is exactly equal to z / 3, as x and y will simplify with themselves ! Thus you simply want the maximum of the grades for each user, divided by the number of grades he has.

So it means need aggregate with `max` and [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) for count with exlude possible missing values and then divide:

```
df1 = df.groupby('user')['grades'].agg(['max','count'])
print (df1)
      max  size
user           
a      12     3
b      11     3
c       8     2
d       9     1

df2 = df1['max'].div(df1['count']).reset_index(name='res')
print (df2)
  user       res
0    a  4.000000
1    b  3.666667
2    c  4.000000
3    d  9.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = df.groupby('user')['grades'].apply(lambda x: (x.sort_values().diff().sum() + x.min())/len(x)).reset_index(name="res")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  user       res
0    a  4.000000
1    b  3.666667
2    c  4.000000
3    d  9.000000
```